# PostQuitMessage() Wont close my app?

Tags: c, winapi

Im trying to write hello world in win32 but when i close the main window, the app continues to run

My window procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```

Event loop:

```
while ((bret = GetMessage(&msg, hWndMain, 0, 0) != 0)
{
    if (bret == -1)
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        return 1;
    }
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Now, then i get WM_DESTROY by clicking on the top-right hand corner x, Instead of GetMessage() returning 0 to signify getting WM_QUIT, it instead returns -1 and GetLastError() whinges about error 1400, which is "invalid window handle"
...I'm perplexed.

Answer (score 11):

Normally you would pass NULL and not a window handle to `GetMessage()`, this would explain why you are getting `ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE` since after `WM_DESTROY` and friends complete, the window will no longer exist. The WM_QUIT posted by `PostQuitMessage()` is a thread message, so GetMessage with a handle will never pick it up.

This is a implementation detail but PostQuitMessage does not even post a real message, it is just a flag stored by the thread and GetMessage will generate the message automatically when required, see [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051104-33/?p=33453) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do this:

```
if (PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE))
{
   if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
   {
      break;
   }

   TranslateMessage(&msg);
   DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```